# C# Activator.CreateInstance Abstract class can't find constructor

Tags: c#, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to get every child of Commands in multiple assembly's to store them in a List but in order to do that i need to create an instance of that child in order to store it but so i am trying to use Activator.CreateInstance the goal is to have a ctor public for outside usage and a ctor for the Activator so it can create instances to store but, problem is that Activator just can't find the ctor for some reason, i even tagged the ctor as public but no luck

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public static List<Command> List { get; set; }
    public static Dictionary<Type, int> Lookup { get; set; }

    public Command(int id, FieldInfo[] field) 
    {
        Id = id;
        Fields = field;
    }

    public Command()
    {
        Command command = List[Lookup[GetType()]];
        Id = command.Id;
        Fields = command.Fields;
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Lookup = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
        List = new List<Command>();

        foreach (Type type in
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Command))))
        {
            Command command = (Command)Activator.CreateInstance(type, List.Count, type.GetFields());
            Lookup.Add(type, command.Id);
            List.Add(command);
        }
    }
}

public class PlayerMove : Command
{

}

[TestClass()]
public class PacketTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void PackTest()
    {
        Command.Initialize();

        Packet packet = new Packet();

        var cmd = new PlayerMove()
        {

        };

        cmd.Send(Method.Unreliable);

        var g = Command.List;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you passing `List.Count, type.GetFields()`? Which overload of `CreateInstance` are you trying to call? Why not just `CreateInstance(type)`?

Comment: Could you please post the code for the class you're actually trying to construct, that's failing? Chances are that doesn't have a suitable constructor

Comment: @Sweeper i'm trying to call 

    public Command(int id, FieldInfo[] field) 
    {
        Id = id;
        Fields = field;
    }

It's supposed to be a private ctor for CreateInstance only, the other one is supposed to be called when a child is instantiated

Comment: @user2696482 But is that constructor also present in the subclasses of `Command`?

Comment: You cannot construct an instance of Command because it is abstract. It doesn't matter if you use reflection, you cannot create an abstract class. You need to have a class that inherits from Command that is not abstract, and you can construct one of those.

Comment: @canton7 I'm calling Command.Initialize() at the start it will look for every child class of Command and store it in the list with the first ctor meanwhile when coding i'll make child classes of Command but when instantiated they will call the second ctor

Comment: @user2696482 I know you're looking for all child classes of Command. But the child class has to have a suitable constructor. Constructors are not inherited in C#. Please show the code for the child class which is causing your exception to be thrown, so that we can check that it has a suitable constructor

Comment: @canton7 here i updated my post

Comment: @user2696482 Are you sure? You edited it to add a space after an `}`

Comment: @SeanReid i'd agree with you but if i pass nothing "Activator.CreateInstance(type)" it will find the default ctor of the abstract class is it because the child class also call the default ctor of its parent idk but i guess i try your solution

Comment: Constructing an instance of a type will only call the constructor of that type, it will not bypass the type and call the constructor of the base class. The `PlayerMove` type only have a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. If you want to be able to pass in the parameters to the constructor in `PlayerMove`, that class also need its own constructor with matching parameters. Constructors are not inherited as such.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to construct an instance of `PlayerMove`. This only has a default constructor, i.e. `PlayerMove()`, which will call the base constructor `Command()`. Therefore your call to `Activator.CreateInstance` should look like

```
Command command = (Command)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Alternatively you should add an additional constructor to the `PlayerMove` class:

```
public class PlayerMove : Command
{
    public PlayerMove(int id, FieldInfo[] field) : base(id, field){}
    public PlayerMove() : base(){}
}
```

But I think that probably what you actually want is something like this:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public static List<Command> List { get; private set; }
    public static Dictionary<Type, int> Lookup { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; }
    public FieldInfo[] Fields { get; }

    protected Command(int id, FieldInfo[] field)
    {
        Id = id;
        Fields = field;
    }

    protected Command()
    {
        Command command = List[Lookup[GetType()]];
        Id = command.Id;
        Fields = command.Fields;
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Lookup = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
        List = new List<Command>();

        foreach (Type type in
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Command))))
        {
            Command command = (Command) Activator.CreateInstance(type, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
                new object[] {List.Count, type.GetFields()}, null);
            Lookup.Add(type, command.Id);
            List.Add(command);
        }
    }
}

public class PlayerMove : Command
{
    private PlayerMove(int id, FieldInfo[] field) : base(id, field)
    {

    }

    public PlayerMove()
    {

    }
}
```

This adds a private constructor to the `PlayerMove` command that is called through reflection and populates the `Id` and `Fields` properties on the base class, and a paramaterless constructor that can then be used by other clients of the class.

Comment: I'm trying to expose less code possible to the child classes isn't it possible to do without adding specifications in child classes ?

Comment: If you want your `Command(int id, FieldInfo[] field)` constructor to be called, the only place it can be called is from child classes. Doesn't matter if you try to use reflection, or write your own IL, you have to have a constructor on the child class that chains down.

Comment: Apparently my previous comment was wrong(ish) - see https://www.strathweb.com/2019/11/instantiating-an-object-without-using-constructor-in-c/ - you can construct an instance without calling any constructors at all (although I wouldn't recommend going down that route.)

Comment: Bummer, i guess i'll just keep the default ctor and check if the command was added else do the logic of the other ctor..